Calculating min value with condition
A column is added to the dataframe with min value for every item just from columns corresponding from dictionary. How can I add a condition when calculating min value - if the values in the selected columns are greater than the values in the column 'Col7'?
import pandas as pd
my_dict={'Item1':['Col1','Col3','Col6'],
'Item2':['Col2','Col4','Col6','Col8']
        }
df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Col0':['Item1','Item2'],
            'Col1':[20,25],
            'Col2':[89,15],
            'Col3':[36,30],
            'Col4':[40,108],
            'Col5':[55,2],
            'Col6':[35,38],
            'Col7':[30,20]
            })

df['min']=df.apply(lambda r:r[[col for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r]].min(),axis=1) 

The result should be:
df=pd.DataFrame({
            'Col0':['Item1','Item2'],
            'Col1':[20,25],
            'Col2':[89,15],
            'Col3':[36,30],
            'Col4':[40,108],
            'Col5':[55,2],
            'Col6':[35,38],
            'Col7':[30,20],
            'min':[35,38]
            })


I'm guessing in the 'min' column you want the minimum value from all columns that is larger than the value in 'Col7' for that row, but shouldn't the value for the second row than be 30 instead of 38? Since 'Col7' contains the value 20 on the second row.

No, not all, but just from columns corresponding from dictionary for every item. For Item1 - 'Col1','Col3','Col6', for Item2 'Col2','Col4','Col6','Col8' ('Col8'  doesn't exist in df and it's ok)

You can get the minimum value and column name by adapting the answer given to your earlier question, passing a default value to min for the case where the condition causes there to be no matching columns:
df[['min', 'name']] = df.apply(
    lambda r:min(((r[col], col) for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r and r[col] > r['Col7']), default=(np.nan, '')),
    axis=1, result_type='expand'
)

Output (for your sample data):
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  min  name
0  Item1    20    89    36    40    55    35    30   35  Col6
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2    38    20   38  Col6

If we change the condition to r[col] > r['Col7']*1.2, the output is
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7   min  name
0  Item1    20    89    36    40    55    35    30   NaN
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2    38    20  38.0  Col6

Note I've used NaN and '' as the default value, you can use whatever you choose in their place.

@Евгения no worries - I'm glad I could help

The receipe would be rather simple:

Retrieve the relevant columns for each row based on Col0 from the  my_dict.
Filter these columns to keep only values greater than the value in Col7.
Finally compute the min of these filtered values.

The above expressed to in code could look like this:
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {
    'Item1': ['Col1', 'Col3', 'Col6'],
    'Item2': ['Col2', 'Col4', 'Col6', 'Col8']
}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col0': ['Item1', 'Item2'],
    'Col1': [20, 25],
    'Col2': [89, 15],
    'Col3': [36, 30],
    'Col4': [40, 108],
    'Col5': [55, 2],
    'Col6': [35, 38],
    'Col7': [30, 20]
})

# Adding the 'min' column by applying 
# a function across each row
df['min'] = df.apply(lambda row: min([row[col] for col in my_dict.get(row['Col0'], []) if col in row and row[col] > row['Col7']]), axis=1)

print(df)


Doesn't work if there are no values satisfying the condition, for ex. if condition  is >(row["Col7"]*1.2) there will be an error:  ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Following the approach you apply, it needs boolean indexing (with gt):
df["min"]= (
    df.apply(lambda r: r.reindex(my_dict[r["Col0"]])
             .loc[lambda s: s.gt(r["Col7"])].min(), axis=1)
)

Output :
    Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  min
0  Item1    20    89    36    40    55    35    30   35
1  Item2    25    15    30   108     2    38    20   38

[2 rows x 9 columns]


Similar to Marcin's answer, you could add and r[col] > r['Col7'] to your condition after if col in r. So that line would look like:
df['min']=df.apply(lambda r:r[[col for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r and r[col] > r['Col7']]].min(),axis=1)


Thanks a lot! Is there a way to get name of the min column? I tried adding .astype(float).idxmin(),axis=1), but it says ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence

Did you replace the .min()? By the code you said? Because that works for me. The 'min' column then holds the column names for the columns with the minimal value (that is above the 'Col7' value). My code: df['min']=df.apply(lambda r:r[[col for col in my_dict.get(r['Col0'], []) if col in r and r[col] > r['Col7']]].astype(float).idxmin(),axis=1)
